# DevExpress XAF: Get Collection of SubCollection

Tags: devexpress, xaf

I have 3 Classes : GrandFother, Persons, Child

```
public class GrandFother: BaseObject
{
[Association("GrandFother_Persons")]
//......
public XPCollection<Persons > GFChilds
{
   get
    {
        return GetCollection<Persons >("GFChilds");
    }
}
}

public class Persons: BaseObject
{
[Association("Persons_Childs")]
// Other code ...
public XPCollection<Child> Childs
{
   get
    {
        return GetCollection<Child>("Childs");
    }
}
//Other code ...
}

public class Child: BaseObject
{
[Association("Persons_Childs")]
// Code ...
}
```

Now, what I want is that, in the class GrandFother, I want to get the list of all Childs that are associated to Persons that belongs to the grandfother

For example:

```
GrangFother1 has two Persons: Person1, Person2.  
Person1 has 2 childs: Per1Ch1, Per1Ch2.    
Person2 has 2 childs: Per2Ch1, Per2Ch2
```

And so, Add an `XPCollection<Child>` to the Class Grandfother  that will contain: Per1Ch1, Per1Ch2, Per2Ch1, Per2Ch2, and if possible with sorting option.

Thanks.

Comment: I [edited your question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing), improving either its formatting, or [its quality](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/02/05/suggested-edits-and-edit-review/) to help people understanding your question, and to help you to get an appropriate answer.
But you still may need to add further information for your question to become fully solvable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `[NonPersistent]` collection property.

```
[NonPersistent]
public XPCollection<Child> GrandChildren
{
    get
    {
        var result = new XPCollection<Child>(Session, GFChilds.SelectMany(x => x.Childs));

        // sorting
        SortingCollection sortCollection = new SortingCollection();
        sortCollection.Add(new SortProperty("Name", SortingDirection.Ascending));
        xpCollectionPerson.Sorting = sortCollection;

        return result;
    }
}
```

But you might not need an `XPCollection<Child>` - an `IList<Child>` will often do.

```
[NonPersistent]
public IList<Child> GrandChildren
{
    get
    {
        return GFChilds
                  .SelectMany(x => x.Childs)
                  .OrderBy(x => x.Name);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very very much. I used XPCollection. the IList made an exception of cast of objects.